# how to get array of contact from [(String?, [Contact])]()?

Tags: swift

I have `var contacts = [(String?, [Contact])]()` I need to extract all contact arrays to put it in `var filteredContacts =  [Contact]()` to be use in search logic.
updatee the Account and Accounts object
//Account

```
struct Account: Codable {
    var id, displayName:String
    var contacts: [Contact]?
...
}
```

//Accounts

```
struct Accounts: Codable {
    let accounts: [Account]
...
}


        switch result {
        case .success(let result):
            
            self.accounts = result.accounts
            self.contacts  = Array(result.accounts
                .compactMap { account in account.contacts.map { (account.displayName , $0) } }.dropFirst())
            self.filteredContacts = ??
```

Comment: What is the type of result.accounts? Looks like it could be easier to start with it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson see the update

Comment: they are a custom object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use `flatMap` and use the second element of the tuple as the `keyPath`:

```
self.filteredContacts = contacts.flatMap(\.1) // for older swift syntax you can use `flatMap { $1 }`
```

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the party but if you want to use accounts or result.accounts directly you can do

```
self.filteredContacts = Array(result.accounts.compactMap(\.contacts).joined())
```

Comment: Why not simply `compactMap(\.contacts).flatMap{$0}` instead of joining and initialising a new array?

Comment: Another option (preferred) is to initialize the contacts property with an empty array and change its declaration to non optional. Then we can simply use `result.accounts.flatMap(\.contacts)`

Answer (score 1):

use a simple for each

```
contacts.forEach({
     self.filteredContacts.append(contentsOf: $0.1)
})
```

Comment: Since Swift 3 you can use $1 instead of $0.1. Btw why not simply flatMap?

Comment: flatmap is better one, is slower since o(n) but just no fancy stuff in case flapmap is not clear as should b.

Comment: I am sure it is not slower than appending. This is exactly how you are supposed to use it. Btw complexity is O(m + n)

Comment: `flatMap` could also be implemented in a way that pre-scans through the results to see total their count, allocates that amount up front, and then copies everything. I remember experimenting with this performance optimization, though IIRC, it's not worth doing for a lot of inputs. But in principle, a smart implementation could hit a fast-path for certain input types.